# ¿Como guardar listas enlazadas dentro de una lista enlazada en PHP?

Tags: php

Me gustaría saber como podría guardar unas listas enlazadas dentro de un nodo de una lista enlazada, algo parecido a la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora he hecho una clase con los métodos de una lista implementados, pero no se como podría hacer para guardar listas dentro de otra lista. Se que este tipo de implementacion se llama listas anidadas pero no encuentro información acerca de ellas.

Acá dejo el código de la clase lista que he hecho

```
  <?php

  //Clase Nodo
  class Nodo{
      function __construct($dato, $siguiente) {
          $this->dato = $dato;
          $this->siguiente = $siguiente;
      }
  }

  //Clase ListaEnlazada
  class ListaEnlazada{
      function __construct() {
          $this->cabecera = null;
          $this->tamLista = 0;
      }

      //Agregar un elemento a la lista
      public function agregarElemento($dato){
          $nuevoNodo = new Nodo($dato, null);

          if(! $this->cabecera){
              $this->cabecera = $nuevoNodo;
          }else{
              $nodoActual = $this->cabecera;

              while($nodoActual->siguiente){
                  $nodoActual = $nodoActual->siguiente;
              }
              $nodoActual->siguiente = $nuevoNodo;
          }
          $this->tamLista++;
      }

      //Agregar un elemento a la lista en una posicion dada
      public function agregarElementoPos($dato, $indice){
          if($indice < 0 || $indice > $this->tamLista){
              echo "Posicion dada fuera del tamaño de la lista";
          }

          $nuevoNodo = new Nodo($dato, null);
          $nodoActual = $this->cabecera;
          $nodoAnterior;

          if($indice == 0){
              $nuevoNodo->siguiente = $nodoActual;
              $this->cabecera = $nodo;
          }else{
              for($i = 0; $i < $indice; $i++){
                  $nodoAnterior = $nodoActual;
                  $nodoActual = $nodoActual->siguiente;
              }
              $nuevoNodo->siguiente = $nodoActual;
              $nodoAnterior->siguiente = $nuevoNodo;
          }
          $this->tamLista++;
      }

      //Eliminar un elemento de la lista
      public function eliminarElemento($dato){
          $nodoActual = $this->cabecera;
          $nodoAnterior = null;

          while($nodoActual != null){
              if($nodoActual->dato == $dato){
                  if(! $nodoAnterior){
                      $this->cabecera = $nodoActual->siguiente;
                  }else{
                      $nodoAnterior->siguiente = $nodoActual->siguiente;
                  }
                  $this->tamLista--;
                  return $nodoActual->dato;
              }
              $nodoAnterior = $nodoActual;
              $nodoActual = $nodoAnterior->siguiente;
          }
          return NULL;
      }

      //Eliminar un elemento en una posicion dada
      public function eliminarElementoPos($indice){
          if($indice < 0 || $indice > $this->tamLista){
              return NULL;
          }
          $nodoActual = $this->cabecera;
          $nodoAnterior = null;

          if($indice == 0){
              $this->cabecera = $nodoActual->siguiente;
          }else{
              for($i = 0; $i < $indice; $i++){
                  $nodoAnterior = $nodoActual;
                  $nodoActual = $nodoActual->siguiente;
              }
              $nodoAnterior->siguiente = $nodoActual->siguiente;
          }
          $this->tamLista--;
          return $nodoActual->dato;
      }

      //Imprimir contenido de la lista
      public function imprimirContenido(){
          if(! $this->tamLista){
              echo "La lista está vacía";
          }

          $elementos = array();
          $nodoActual = $this->cabecera;

          while($nodoActual != null){
              array_push($elementos, $nodoActual->dato);
              $nodoActual = $nodoActual->siguiente;
          }

          $valores = '';

          foreach($elementos as $dato){
              $valores .= $dato. ' --> ';
          }

          echo $valores."X";
      }

      //Saber si la lista esta vacia
      public function listaVacia(){
          if($this->tamLista == 0){
              echo "Lista vacía";
          }else{
              echo "Lista con elementos";
          }
      }

      //Saber si el numero de elementos en la lista
      public function obtenerTamaño(){
          return $this->tamLista;
      }
  }
```

Comment: una forma seria pensar que el $dato que va a contener la lista enlazada, es precisamente un objeto tipo Nodo. Si todo lo anterior lo tienes bien (la primera lista te funciona), entonces crea en cada $dato un nuevo Nodo, y trabaja con el.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas JSON para esto?

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que me dices @Jakala lo que intente fue aplicar el metodo agregarElemento() dentro del mismo y funciono, hice lo siguiente: $listaEnlazada->add($listaEnlazada->add(12), $listaEnlazada->add(10));              Mi salida fue la siguiente: ListaEnlazada Object ( [cabecera] => Nodo Object ( [dato] => 12 [siguiente] => Nodo Object ( [dato] => 10 [siguiente] => Nodo Object ( [dato] => [siguiente] => ) ) )                                                                         No se si te refieras a esto

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia me podría dar algún ejemplo de como puedo implementar esto? @A.Cedano